# React- Context provider rerenders with the same values the consumers

Tags: reactjs

I have this simple provider/consumer case and i noticed that the child's 3 consumer always rerenders even when the provider provides the same value.

As doc says

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render
>   whenever the Provider’s value prop changes. The propagation from
>   Provider to its descendant consumers (including .contextType and
>   useContext) is not subject to the shouldComponentUpdate method, so the
>   consumer is updated even when an ancestor component skips an update.

In this case the value doesnt change, but why child3 rerenders?

```
const UserContext1 = React.createContext({
  name: "Guest1"
}); 



class Child3 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext1.Consumer>
        {user => {
          console.log(user);
          return <div>ssssssssssssssss</div>;
        }}
      </UserContext1.Consumer>
    );
  }
}


class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { name: "George" };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <UserContext1.Provider value='hello'>
          <Child3/>
        </UserContext1.Provider>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ name: "hey" });
          }}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate
"The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either implement `shouldComponentUpdate` or use React.memo (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) with a functional component if you're using react 16.8+.